# Spring not injecting DAOs into JSF managed beans with abstract superclass

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I have a JSF 2.0 application and I am integrating Spring so I can make use of the hibernateTemplate. I already consulted the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver) on JSF integration and have taken steps to set it up. All of my bean classes extend an abstract super class called SuperBean. SuperBean is the desired point of injection, saving me from having to declare all of my beans in Spring. I was hoping to just declare it as abstract="true" and any subclass bean extending the SuperBean class would have the dao injected. At runtime it is null.

```
<bean id="serviceTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
   <property name="transactionAttributes">
      <props>
         <prop key="*"/>
      </props>
   </property>
</bean>
<bean id="daoServiceTarget" class="com.example.service.DaoService">
       <property name="mainDAO" ref="mainDAO"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="daoService" parent="serviceTemplate">
       <property name="target" ref="daoServiceTarget"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="superBean" class="com.example.beans.SuperBean" abstract="true">
       <property name="daoService" ref="daoService"/>
    </bean>
```

Am I able to simply declare this superclass SuperBean and expect Spring to inject the dao? I don't want to have to declare every bean class in spring.

I suppose the alternative option (from a performance perspective) would be to not use Spring beans but declare the DAO's as @applicationScoped and inject them into the SuperBean class using JEE's CDI. Would this be better performance-wise?

Answer (score 1):

In the example above it looks serviceTemplate is providing an example of what you want.  Note the parent="serviceTemplate".  You need to do something similar to those who inherit from superbean.  There are other options but since you have working code in the serviceTemplate that might be the best place to start.  Then read [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) for more details:

Comment: I added the serviceTemplate bean definition. It's just another abstract class provided by spring. I would like to avoid having to define every bean in spring. My SuperBean class has a method setDaoService(DaoService dao){//set attr}. All beans that are a subclass should have the DAO because a SubBean is a SuperBean. Is this possible?